# How can I structure tables for easy using Laravel relationship?

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have a little complex relationship in tables and want to structure the relationship for the easy using EloquenrORM relationship functions.

```
- users
    - id
    - name
- teams
    - id
    - name
- team_user
    - id
    - team_id
    - user_id

- course
    - id
    - name
- pathway
    - id
    - name
- pathway_course
    - id
    - pathway_id
    - course_id
```

This is a LMS project and can assign any pathway/course to any user/group
I want to know how I can structure the relationship between pathway/course and user/group.
Thanks.

What I tried was to make assignments table like this:

```
- assignments
    id
    user_id
    group_id
    assignmentable_id
    assignmentable_type
```

But this seems not a solution.

Comment: It seems like a polymorphic relationship is exactly what you need. Why is that "not a solution?"

Answer (score 0):

you can use a table like this:

```
- assignments
    id
    assignee_type (e.g: 'user' or 'team')
    assignee_id
    assinmentable_type
    assignmentable_id
```

but maybe the relationships query will be a little tricky.

You can also have the following structure:

```
- assignments
    id
    assinmentable_type
    assignmentable_id
```

basically a polymorphic one-to-many relationship and then:

```
- assignee_assignment
    assignee_type (e.g: 'user' or 'team')
    assignee_id
    assinment_id
```

which is a polymorphic many-to-many relationship.